# How to add a ODataUriResolver to the default ODataUriParser

Tags: odata, odata-v4, odatalib

I created an OData v4 EndPoint using OData-WebApi and ODataLib.

I want to add a new ODataUriResolver to the default ODataUriParser which the ODataWebApi is using.

I know how to add a custom ODataUriResolver to a new instacne of ODataUriParser but not to the instance which the server is using.

Is there a a place where I can add a new ODataUriResolver to the default ODataUriParser?
Is there a place where I can create a new ODataUriParser of myself?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you can derived from DefaultODataPathHandler, in the overwritten function "Parse", you can create your own ODataUriResolver and set it into ODataUriParser before using it to parse the Uri.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could just use all the behavior of DefaultOdataPathHandler and ovveride only the UriParser its using.